# Rupee symbol is not visible in windows server 2003

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, globalization, culture

I have a `winform` application.In this application I have implemented culture `globalization` for different countries like USA, Frans and India. And I have to test this culture on `windows server 2003` OS. When my culture is set to USA all the currency format set to $ before amount.But when I set this culture to INDIA rupee symbol is not getting visible.Instead of Rupee symbol it is showing square as i have attached two images for dollar sign and rupee sign in `datagridview`.

```
Dollar symbol in Datagridview
```

[image]

```
Rupees Symbol in Datagridview
```

[image]

I have set `Datagridview` font to `ARIAL` for containing rupee symbol but it is not showing ₹ (Rupee Symbol) as given in attached image.I am checking it on windows server 2003. I have install two fonts `Mangal` and `Mangal Bold` for getting rupee symbol but still not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that INR got its own symbol only in 2010 (Unicode U+20B9). Microsoft added support for the symbol in Aug 2010, via [KB2496898](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898) for Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2.

But Windows Server 2003 did not get this enhancement as it was already in Extended Support Phase from July 2010.

Comment: So there is no way to show rupee symbol in window server 2003. If there is any such font that it supports or upgrade of OS?